# What is the best tool to find duplicate code in android project?

Tags: android

I want to find all duplicate codes in my android project so can anyone suggest which is the best tool for the same and it should be pluggable with Eclipse IDE.

Regards,
Piks

Comment: I see this justification for closing frequently and it is very irritating.  The reason the question is asked is precisely so that someone's opinion will be offered.  I want to see those opinions and the research that backs them up so as to save me the effort of repeating it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use http://pmd.sourceforge.net/cpd.html .It can be used to find duplicate code and it works like a charm.

I just did a search for duplicate code at http://marketplace.eclipse.org and found the PMD plugin at http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/pmd-eclipse

You can use http://pmd.sf.net/eclipse as the update site to get the plugin

Comment: Thanks a lot, i run once and it gives the result which i am expecting.

Answer (score 0):

`Lint` present in ADT will help you a long way in finding a lot of duplicate naming and so on. Not sure what you mean by duplicate code? static analysis?

Comment: By duplicate code he meant, copy/paste code